# How to get the data from Database with a set of string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have a set of string which is:

```
"1,2,5,6,9,17,24"
```

and each of them are User IDs for the "user" table.

How can I get multiple rows of data from a table where the `userID` are those specified in the of String?

A suggestion I've had is to split the string with substring and `for` loop each of the IDs in the `dbhelper`, but I have no idea to do that.

Here is the code for my `Activity`:

```
private void loadChatData() {
    String GroupName = Groupname;
    String participantID = dbHelper.getParticipantID(GroupName);
    participants = dbHelper.getParticipantList(participantID);
    madapter = new FriendListByGridAdapter(GroupinformationActivity.this, participants);
    groupdetailsdelist.setAdapter(madapter);
    madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the output for the **participantID** is "1,2,5,6,9,17,24".

Here is the code for the method in `DBHelpers`:

```
  public List<Friend> getParticipantList(String participantID) {
      openForWrite();
      List<Friend> list = new ArrayList<Friend>();
      String selectQuery ="SELECT "
            + KEY_FRIEND_NAME + ","
            + KEY_PICTURE
            + " FROM "
            + TABLE_FRIEND
            + " WHERE "
            + KEY_FRIEND_ID + " = "
            + "'"+ participantID + "'";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{});

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            Friend temp = new Friend();
            temp.setFriendpicture(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PICTURE)));
            temp.setFriend_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FRIEND_NAME)));

            list.add(temp);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    Log.d("friend list","" + list.size());
    return list;
}
```

I just want to get all the `friendName`s and `picturepath`s to display in a `listview` corresponding to the `userID`s which are in the string.

Here's an example of my "Friend" table:
[Table_Friend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuN2A.png)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein
nono sir! String array is 1,2,5,6,9,17,24 and each of it are **KEY_FRIEND_ID**
example in the database:
1     MellisaNg          Female     0100000000  ||||
2     Frank N. Stein   Male         0200000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
String participentIDArray[] = participentID.split(",");
List<Friend> list = new ArrayList<Friend>();
for(int i = 0; i < participentIDArray.length; i++) {
    list.addAll(getDataFromDatabase(participentIDArray[i]));
}
madapter = new FriendListByGridAdapter(GroupinformationActivity.this, list);
groupdetailsdelist.setAdapter(madapter);
madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

method to get data from database based in participentID:

```
public ArrayList<Friend> getDataFromDatabase() {
    List<Friend> list = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    // Add your code to get data from database
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to fetch all ids in 1 query. So you can just create a simple sql, e.g.:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE_FRIEND WHERE KEY_FRIEND_ID in (participantID)";
```

and then use:

```
db.rawQuery(sql,null);
```

Comment: @FrankN.Stein how to change the getParticipantList() method signature to accept a string array

Comment: I based my comment on this:
String participantID = dbHelper.getParticipantID(GroupName);

Comment: You're completely right, I overlooked the question.